# Using miles or kilometers in Flutter application?

Tags: internationalization, flutter

Greetings Flutter Devs,

I'm writing an internationalized app and trying to determine whether to use miles or kilometers based on the locale. Currently I can only see the country and language from the locale data structure. Is there a way to determine whether the app should use miles or kilometers?

Thanks!

James

Comment: Shouldn't be difficult to build a table for that yourself. There aren't many countries using imperial system anymore. It would perhaps to allow the user to chose instead of making it dependent on the country.

Comment: Thanks... yes. I my settings window I plan to give the choice of "Automatic" which will be default or allow the user to set it to miles or kilometers.  I also have the same issue with 12h vs. 24h time, but thought I would add that as a separate SO question if the answer to the miles / km question does not point me in the right direction for 12h vs 24h time.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/alwaysUse24HourFormat.html

> Whether to use 24-hour format when formatting time.
>
> The behavior of this flag is different across platforms:
>
> - On Android this flag is reported directly from the user settings
>     called "Use 24-hour format". It applies to any locale used by the
>     application, whether it is the system-wide locale, or the custom
>     locale set by the application.
> - On iOS this flag is set to true when
>     the user setting called "24-Hour Time" is set or the system-wide
>     locale's default uses 24-hour formatting.

See also https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Comment: How does this relates to miles vs kilometers?

Comment: See comments below the question.

Comment: Thanks! Will upvote that one as it answers my time question. (oops... as a newbie, my upvote doesn't count yet!)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Günter response - afaik only USA, Myanmar and Liberia uses the imperial system. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You can use the following snippet `Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode` to get the current country code.

Click on the [following link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Locale/countryCode.html) to get more information.

Comment: The UK still uses miles, but have standardized on Kg for mass (weight)... except, of course, I still hear them use the term "stone" when describing the weight of people (go figure!).

Comment: Tried to upvote this as well as it appears that this is the only approach that works. But I don't have 15 reputation points yet, so it won't reflect in the public vote tally. Sorry!

Comment: There are a lot more, if you also include territories: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile